# How can I get the scrollbar position on panel? WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, scrollbar

I'm trying to get the scrollbar position on a panel, but it olny works if I scroll it by clicking and dragging the scroolbar or clicking its scrolling buttons.

If I scroll the panel using the mouse wheel it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
if (mypanel.HorizontalScroll.Value > 500)
        {
            lbl1.Text = "A";
        }
        if (mypanel.HorizontalScroll.Value < 300)
        {
            lbl1.Text = "B";
        }
```

Comment: The mouse wheel scrolls vertically, not horizontally.  Did your monitor fall over?

Comment: Actually in my app it scrolls horizontally because I don't have a vertical scrollbar.
How can I do what you say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Scroll` and `MouseWheel` are different. When you scroll, that means you have to use the `ScrollBar` to scroll it, the message `WM_HSCROLL` and `WM_VSCROLL` will be sent to the control. When you use `Mouse` you can also scroll with a condition that there is 1 child control **focused** in the `scrollable container like Panel`, the message `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` will be sent to the control. So to achieve what you want, you have to register handlers for both the events `Scroll` and `MouseWheel` like this:

```
private void HandleScroll(){
    if (mypanel.HorizontalScroll.Value > 500) {
        lbl1.Text = "A";
    }
    else if (mypanel.HorizontalScroll.Value < 300) {
        lbl1.Text = "B";
    }
}
//place this code in your form constructor after InitializeComponent()
panel1.Scroll += (s,e) => {
   HandleScroll();
};
panel1.MouseWheel += (s,e) => {  
   HandleScroll();
};
```

Comment: It didn't work. The problem is that when I scroll using the mouse wheel, the HorizontalScroll.Value doesnt' update.

Comment: @user2558874 I tested it and it worked for me, you should have said that *It didn't work for me*, Be sure that the `Horizontal ScrollBar` appears. That happens when the contents are stacked horizontally.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I've made a terrible mistake, I forgot to change "panel1" for my panel's name.